# Amazon S3: Add 301 redirects long list of URIs on static site

Tags: amazon-s3, static-site

I have a static site hosted on S3 with Cloudfront. I have a list of URLs containing content that has been deleted, and I need to set up 301 redirects for all of them to the same page. The list is very long; what's the most scalable way to set the redirects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you can simply create a cloudFront distribution to your bucket and configure Error Pages.

Here is a tutorial of how setting up a CloutFront distribution with S3 bucket: [Configure CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/GettingStarted.html)

And inside your distribution, you can redirect all "not found" requests to not-found.html for example.